# How to define global variables only if an event has occured in JS?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
var wasClicked = false;
function constructRow() {
    var row = new Array(4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        row[i] = document.createElement("td");
        row[i].addEventListener("click", function () { clicked(); })
    }
}

function clicked() {
    wasClicked = true;
}
```

And I want to define some global variables only if there was a click, hence if `wasClicked == true`, Like this:

```
if(wasClicked) {
    var first = 1;
    var second = 2;
    var third = 3;
}
```

Is there a way I can do that? To define these variables only if `wasClicked`?

Comment: You can set them in the `clicked` function but if you mean automatically then no.

Comment: There are no such things as a "variable changed" listeners, only DOM event listeners so you'd have to add this logic into the `clicked` function

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Like this is the wrong approach to whatever you're trying to solve by doing this.

Comment: It seems that your approach for doing what you want is a wrong approach. Can you tell us more what you want to do then ? why do you want to define variables there ?

Comment: Sure. I am programming a checkers game, and I just want to define some variables only if a piece was clicked to make my code more efficient. I simplified it for the question's purpose.

Comment: If I define them in the `clicked` function, how can I make them global? I need them for later use in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working over browser you can make the variable global just

> window.variableName=value

for your code you can write it like this

```
if(wasClicked) {
    window.first = 1;
    window.second = 2;
    window.third = 3; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use these variables afterwards using your solution?

Comment: yup! but this approach is not quite good as per coding standards. you should always declare the global variable at starting of the file or program

Comment: Great! I know you're right about my approach, but there's an issue with it. I am doing something more complex, so the values are derived from a global one which changes only if there was an event. So If I don't have this condition, they won't be defined and I'll achieve nothing. That's a special case.

Comment: Hi, I used this solution and it seems that the variables are undefined when I use them in later functions. What should I do?

Comment: hey if you don't mind can please show your code, to know how you are using them and for what scenario

Comment: It's quite complex. I'll try to simplify it

Comment: Can I globalize a variable in a function? Meaning that I define global variables inside a function?  Will your way fit it?

Comment: yah! you can do that also you can use this and arrow function inside it

Comment: How should I use it? I'm not quite familiar with them

Comment: @NoobMaster I think this example will help you
`(function global(){
         a=5;
        const child=()=>{
               this.b=5;
       }
         child();
       console.log(a+b);
})()`